# Kotlin - Changing map styles according to phones time

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to change maps style based off the time of the day. At 6.00pm I want to change it to the night map and at 6.00am I want to change it to the day map. Currently, I think its always returning the night map even though it is daytime. Here is what I have at the moment. I am trying to compare the times but might have the wrong format.

```
    val startNight = "18:00"
    val startDay = "6:00"
    val formatDate = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
    val parseNight = formatDate.parse(startNight)
    val parseDay = formatDate.parse(startDay)

    val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().time;

    if (currentTime.after(parseNight)) {
        mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.night_style))
    } else if (currentTime.after(parseDay)) {
        mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.day_style))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Running these in the Kotlin REPL yields the answer:

```
parseNight
Thu Jan 01 18:00:00 GMT 1970

parseDay
Thu Jan 01 06:00:00 GMT 1970
```

The parsed times are assuming a date of Jan 1st 1970. You could fix the current implementation by specifying the dates by hand too, but a better way of doing it is using the new Java 8 date utilities:

```
val now = LocalDateTime.now()
// 6 AM today
val morning = now.withHour(6).withMinute(0)
// 6 PM today
val evening = now.withHour(18).withMinute(0)

val isDaytime = now.isBefore(evening) and now.isAfter(morning)

if (isDaytime) { showDayTimeMap() } else { showNightTimeMap() }
```

Better still would be using LocalTime instead of LocalDateTime, but this wouldn't exemplify how to deal with the date issues.

Comment: Added an alternative implementation